# How to setup a display environment?

Tags: scripting, x11

I'm using MNE (a program to analyse data) in Linux CentOS 6. I upgraded my system to Linux CentOS 7 and after that I was unable to run MNE GUI. Whenever I started the program I'd get the following message:

```
MNE can not connect to X server
DISPLAY is not set. please set your DISPLAY environment variable"
```

I am sourcing my MNE script. The content of this script :

```
#!/bin/tcsh
setenv MNE_ROOT /usr/pubsw/packages/mne/stable
setenv SUBJECTS_DIR /autofs/space/mrga/construct/mast/wsat/
setenv MATLAB_ROOT /usr/pubsw/packages/matlab/current
source $MNE_ROOT/bin/mne
```

after then I am calling the program by writing mne in terminal

This is how I was doing it in Linux Centos 6

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you starting the program? This shouldn't happen if you're starting it from your GUI session.

Comment: @Gilles. The same way as I was doing in my Linux Centos 6 from the terminal I source the program then calling MNI !!

Comment: Please copy-paste the exact command that you're using, as well as the output of `export | grep -E 'DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY'`. If you're sourcing a script, post the content of that script as well, maybe it's doing something strange. If you run some other program from the same terminal, for example `xterm`, does it work?

Comment: @Gilles . See updated. xtrem is running

Comment: Do you run tcsh in the terminal? How exactly do you call your “MNE script” (the one that starts with `#!/bin/tcsh` followed by a bunch of `setenv`)? What about the output of ` output of export | grep -E 'DISPLAY|XAUTHORITY'` at the point you would start `mne`?

Answer (score 1):

If the application is being executed locally you can set the environment variable `$DISPLAY` like so in a terminal:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Afterwards you can then invoke MNI in the same terminal:

```
$ ...MNI command...
```